# Factor ordering not working with levels and ordered -r

Tags: r

I am stuck on a very basic thing with ordered factors in R
I do use `factor`, `levels`, `ordered=TRUE`, but it still does not put my factors in ORDER!
Please help. I am not seeing the obvious...

```
data_ordered<-data%>% 
  mutate(
    mocc <- factor(mocc, levels = c("0", "1", "2", "3"), ordered = TRUE)
  )

ordered(data_ordered$mocc)
```

Levels: 3 < 2 < 1 < 0

I am an idiot but where?

Comment: Your factors _are_ ordered. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: but not in the correct order : i need "0" to be the lowest and "3" to be the highest